# Why my webpage title not same as expected?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages, html-title

Here is my website - [Aman Roy](http://amanroy.me)

The problem is that from some days the title of my website is showing **HOME | aman-roy.github.io**

previously it is showing **HOME | Aman Roy**

Even now, locally it is showing **HOME | Aman Roy** but not on the GitHub pages.

Codes of my website resides here - [GitHub Link to website codes](http://github.com/aman-roy/aman-roy.github.io)

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without the need to go outside SO

Comment: This happened to me too! How did you fix it? I can see that your repo's url is no longer appended to your website's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your home page does not have the `<title>` element defined so Jekyll is most likely generating one by itself based on the index.html Jekyll title set and the URL.

Add the following to your `<head>` located in your `default.html`
([master/_layouts/default.html](https://github.com/aman-roy/aman-roy.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html))

`<title>{{ page.title }} | {{ site.author }}</title>`

Comment: I do have what you said but there's still this github repo's url appended to my title e.g. `| repo-name.github.io`, which is annoying.

Comment: @JasonGao Do you mind linking your github pages repo so I can have a look?

Comment: @JasonGao I think you are right with your suspicion, your page meta title setup looks fine. Maybe check your github pages domain redirect setting or something.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just realized it probably came from the plugin i used: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag